# How do I extract specific lines based on a comparison of two files with sed and/or awk?

Tags: awk, sed

I need to extract all the lines from file2.txt that do not match the string until the first dot in any line in file1.txt. I am interested in a solution that stays as close to my current approach as possible so it is easy for me to understand, and uses only sed and/or awk in linux bash.

file1.h

```
apple.sweet banana
apple.tasty banana
apple.brown banana
orange_mvp.rainy day.here
orange_mvp.ear nose.png
lemon_mvp.ear ring
tarte_mvp_rainy day.here
```

file2.h

```
orange_mvp
lemon_mvp
lemon_mvp
tarte_mvp
cake_mvp
```

result desired

```
tarte_mvp
cake_mvp
```

current wrong approach

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { sub(/mvp(\..*)$/,""); a[$0]; next }
            { f=$0; sub(/mvp(\..*)$/,"", f) }
    !(f in a)
' file2.h file1.h

apple.sweet banana
apple.tasty banana
apple.brown banana
orange_mvp.rainy day.here
orange_mvp.ear nose.png
lemon_mvp.ear ring
tarte_mvp_rainy day.here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F. 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1;next} a[$1] != $0' file1.h file2.h
tarte_mvp
cake_mvp
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @HatLess is very nice and idiomatic. If you find it a bit cryptic, you can also consider this one, in program `program.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    while(getline prefix < "file1.txt") {
    gsub("[.].*", "", prefix)
    ignore[prefix]
    }
}

!($0 in ignore) {
    print($0)
}
```

Invoked with `awk -f program.awk file2.txt`.

In the BEGIN block we read all the lines from `file1.txt` and store the prefixes we want to ignore as keys of an hash table.

Then we process the `file2.txt` and print all the lines which are selected (not ignored).